# Download file information from the youtube api v2 playlist

Tags: youtube-api

I want get the file ID found in the youtube playlist.

**Example:**
[FROM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uelHwf8o7_U&index=1&list=RDEMASZzAB4N6PSfsOwzAhxYyQ) 
I want to download a list of files in the form of movie id:

```
watch? v = uelHwf8o7_U
watch? v = wfWIs2gFTAM  .. ..
```

Unfortunately, I cannot do this with youtube api v2. Is there anyway that I can do this? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do, not what happened that made you sad

Comment: I want to get the IDs of all files through the id of the playlist Youtube

Comment: Edit your question, consult this page for a better quality question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [PlaylistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list). Just provide the playlistID and it will list all the videos in that playlist including their corresponding File properties (ID, title, etc.).

Comment: In this case, me need a "youtube key". I would like to retrieve this information without having a key

Comment: try swimming without water